# Run a URL and get the new link

Tags: c#, webrequest

I want to run a URL and get the result.
I used the below code but it does not work correctly. It just returns the main website URL as a result.
this is the main [page](https://www.gfxtra.com/vectors/vector-designelements/vector-label-sticker/624520-20-name-badges-cm-206969.html) which has a blue box is called filenext. I get its link and [this](https://www.filenext.com/cydv4pgffvh6/206969.20.Name.Badges-16092018.rar.html) is what I want to get as a result.

```
                    WebClient client = new WebClient();
                    client.Headers.Add("user-agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.2; .NET CLR 1.0.3705;)");
                    WebClient getNitroflareLink = new WebClient();


                    HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url) as HttpWebRequest;
                    HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
                    Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set `Referer`from the first URL for the second one.

```
        var page = firstLink.LoadIt();
            HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(Refererlink) as HttpWebRequest;
            request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.113 Safari/537.36";
            request.Referer = firstLink;
            using (HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)
```